# How to retrieve results of Poweshell script back in C# objects?

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to execute a PowerShell script through C#. My script will create a `.csv` file at a location specified. The below code creates a file at the location specified, but I want the code to return an object which has all the content/data the file has. Is that possible?

```
RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration))
{
    runspace.Open();
    RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    Command scriptCommand = new Command(@"C:\powershell.ps1");

    Collection<CommandParameter> commandParameters = new Collection<CommandParameter>();

    pipeline.Commands.Add(scriptCommand);

    Collection<PSObject> psObjects;
    psObjects = pipeline.Invoke();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you rather make use of `Powershell` APIs?

For example:

```
PowerShell psinstance = PowerShell.Create();
psinstance.AddScript(scriptPath);
var results = psinstance.Invoke();
```

More details can be found here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/

Answer (score 0):

You can return file content from powershell with [this command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) and then write powershell output to the PSDataCollection.

```
  private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Process(string command)
    {
        var output = new List<string>();

        using (var powerShell = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powerShell.AddScript(command);

            var outputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();

            await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                powerShell.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outputCollection),
                result =>
                {
                    OnDeployEnd?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                    foreach (var data in outputCollection)
                    {
                        output.Add(data.ToString());
                    }
                }
            );

            if (powerShell.HadErrors)
            {
                var errorsReport = powerShell.Streams.Error.GetErrorsReport();
                throw new Exception(errorsReport);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
```